# How to add class to a file link in Twig

Tags: theming

I'm trying to add a button class to an **internal file URL**. The field itself is a normal file field type. Below is the twig code that I have tried to use with no success. I'm also using this code in a twig field template.

```
{% for item in items %}
 <a class="usa-button" href="{{ item.content['#url'] }}">{{ item.content['#title']}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You should preprocess this field so the class is passed into the template and handled in rendering without having to resort to this.

Comment: You could also use the [link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates#link) function to do something similar. Best practice guide for twig apparently mentions that it may not always be a good idea to use render arrays for links. I guess this could be an answer..., but I'm not really sure of it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the guidance everyone. Much appreciated!